# Cassandra-driver for Node is not connecting to ScyllaDB server

Tags: node.js, cassandra, scylla, cassandra-driver

This question is for Cassandra as well.

I am using the Cassandra-driver packagae in Node to connect to my ScyllaDB node. The node can be accessed via cqlsh from other linux machines outside of its network. However, when I am using Windows to connect to it via a Node application, it is unable to reach the host. I have tried with ports 9042, 9160 and a few others as well.

Previously, I was using Docker to host multiple ScyllaDB nodes in the same Linux VM and Docker was finally exposing them via port 80 - which I was able to connect to, via the Node application.

Where do you think is the problem? Does Windows have a problem connecting to Scylla/Cassandra nodes?

P.S.: The Scylla node is hosted on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Azure.

Comment: I recommend tracing the connection with wireshark. Is the connection established? What data is exchanged?

Comment: Can I see your scylla config? I'm particularly interested in the rpc_address and listen_address.

`grep -v "^$" /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml | grep -v "^#"`

Also, can you run a simple telnet test from windows? 

`telnet myScyllaIP 9042`